# how many number of nodes we can create under hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

Is there any limit of creating number of nodes while configuring hyperledger fabric?

I have gone through the below answer but I'm not clear what he is explaining.

[Limit of number of nodes in Hyperledger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677588/limit-of-number-of-nodes-in-hyperledger)

When I say number of nodes, it could be number of stakeholders(marked as organizations) or peers or endorser nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer on that post is now incorrect. Fabric does not currently used Byzantine Fault Tolerance, it only has Crash Tolerance through Kafka ordering. Byzantine Fault Tolerance is estimated to come around Fabric 1.4.

With Kafka, there is not a limit on the number of nodes. There is a performance hit as you introduce nodes, Hyperledger Sawtooth is known to be better for node scalability

[image: Hyperledger uses voting based, while Sawtooth used lottery-based]

Comment: In hyperledger fabric is there any scalability when we add new nodes? What is the best practice on adding nodes, to maintain a good performance how many number of nodes to be restricted?

Comment: The big issue at the moment is there are little best practices released unfortunately. 


A benchmarking tool called Caliper has recently been adopted by Hyperledger to specifically try and discover these things: [link](https://www.hyperledger.org/blog/2018/03/19/measuring-blockchain-performance-with-hyperledger-caliper) 

I believe we are talking about nodes in the thousands when you should be choosing Sawtooth instead.

Comment: can you send any references links from the official website that there is no limit for adding the number of nodes under hyperledger?

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit to creating the number of nodes in fabric ( that's the idea behind distributed system) but be aware that as and when you start adding more and more nodes, you may see the performance being adversely hit when you do the transactions.

Answer (score 0):

As per my recent conversations with the teams which have implemented Hyperledger Fabric on version 1.1 it seems the performance is okay for upto 16 to 18 nodes. It seems to be a trade off due to the faster finality demonstrated by Hyperledger Fabric.

Answer (score -1):

In Hyperledger Fabric, nodes can be of type orderers, endrosing peers or clients.

1. If we are talking about how many **Byzantine** nodes, then the precise answer is as follows: a) There is ***no limit*** on Byzantine peers and clients. If there are too many of them, a client just won't be able to get his transaction endorsed. However the integrity of the system is not endangered. b) Since the consensus algorithm is run between the *orderers*, then the limit depends on that specific algorithm used. Remember Hyperledger Fabric supports *pluggable* consensus, meaning that the consensus algorithm is not necessarily hardcoded. In its current implementation, Hypeledger Fabric runs "Kafka" which is NOT Byzantine-Fault tolerant. This means that **even one** Byzantine orderer can compromise the whole system! However, there are plans for BFT-Smart which is Byzantine-Fault tolerant and supports up to 33% faulty nodes, as the above answer says.
2. If we are talking about the **total number** of nodes, then the precise answer is as follows: a) There is (theoretically) ***no limit*** on the number of clients-peers. b) The *practical* limit of orderers again depends on the consensus. For BFT, this translates up to practically 10 (maybe 20) orderers.